# Script for checking if a video on page exist and display it?

Tags: php, javascript, api, video, tags

I'm trying to detect if a page has a video. If it does then display it on the page. I've seen this done with sites like youtube but I need something to pull in more sites like vimeo, blog video sites like tumblr and so on.

Is there a script that just searches for video on a page?

Any help is much appreciated or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to provide specs like - flash video? html5 video? both? Display it on what page? What sites are you searching? Maybe why in the world you are doing this...

Comment: both, all types of video, Display it on my own page. Searching youtube, vimeo, blogs with their own video flash. Need it easier for users to submit links and my site will find the video and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a find on the body using a video embed selector.

(Using JQuery)

```
$('body').find('embed').css('display','block');
```